# Visual Studio 2015 Play Button for NPM Scripts

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm

Is there a way to get the VS 2015 Play Button to execute an NPM script in node tools for VS?

Ideally I would like to have developers click the "run" button, and it executes `npm run watch` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Pre and Post Build Actions**

You may find it necessary to run a script or process immediately before or after build. This is achieved with minimal effort when using Node.js Tools for Visual Studio. A small bit of xml code needs to be added to the Node.js project file (.njsproj) and your custom action will be called on build. Place this code just before  in the project file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PreBuildEvent>
      PRE BUILD ACTION
  </PreBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>
      POST BUILD ACTION
  </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

These actions are run as if they were run manually through cmd.exe. You could use this to do just about any custom action before or after build.

docs [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Pre-and-Post-Build-Actions)